# Heat/Fire hazard with over the range convection oven?

Tags: heat, kitchen-safety, convection, fire

I'm interested in getting a new combination convection/microwave oven that would fit over the range. There are wooden cabinets just above and around the space where I currently have a microwave. Would there be any safety issue or heat/fire hazard having a convection oven in that space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual for any sort of oven should specify the necessary clearance required in each direction. Since different machines will differ in operating temperature, insulation, construction etc., there's no general answer we can give here other than to check the manual before purchasing and take the requirements seriously.

Answer (score 1):

There are convection ovens specifically designed to go over the range, some of which also can be used to vent smells/smoke from the range. Those will (obviously) be safe to use over a range.